# Function nullifies parameters for no apparent reason

Tags: c++, function

I'm writing my first 'big' assignment for programming classes. The program should go through a vector containing coordinates and find the biggest possible perimeter of a triangle. I've almost done it and was already celebrating when i ran into a problem. A function processing the whole thing nullifies the integers containing indexes of points.  Here's the function in question:

```
double Process (vector<vector<int>> &vec,int PointMaxi,int PointMaxj, int PointMaxk)
{
    double MaxP;
    int i=0,j=0,k=0;
    PointMaxi=0;PointMaxj=1;PointMaxk=2;
    MaxP=Perimeter(0,1,2,vec);
    int size=vec.size();
    while(i<size)
    {
        while (j<size)
        {
            while (k<size)
            {
                if(((i!=j)&&(j!=k))&&Perimeter(i,j,k,vec)>=MaxP)
                {
                    MaxP=Perimeter(i,j,k,vec);
                    PointMaxi=i;
                    PointMaxj=j;
                    PointMaxk=k;
                }
                k++;
            }
            k=0;
            j++;
        }
        j=0;
        i++;
    }
    return MaxP;
 }
```

So when the function quits PointMaxi,PointMaxj and PointMaxk (great naming i know) all become zeroes and i can't output the points of maximum perimeter.
I've been staring at it for hours, googling even more and i still can't figure out the problem. Somebody please, help.

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: Pass them as reference

Comment: as qwr wrote: the prototype should be: `double Process (vector<vector<int>> &vec,int &PointMaxi,int &PointMaxj, int &PointMaxk)` not by value as you did.

Comment: Is it possible your vector of vectors of ints is supposed to just be a vector of ints?

Comment: @trojansdestroy no, the inner vector represents a polygon and the outer a list of polygons. Poor encapsulation, but lets cut him some slack before getting into these issues.

Comment: @trojansdestroy What's poor about it? What is the right way? Should i use vectors here at all?
And thank you guys, passing them is reference was enough to make it all work.

Comment: There isn't necessarily a correct way, and your way isn't incorrect (merely dense, in my opinion). My critique was a result of my own failure to understand, but others could have caught on easily (probably due to my own lack of experience).

Comment: Regarding encapsulation: it would simplify your code, making it easier to write and debug (for you), while making it easier to learn and understand (for anyone else). In this case, I'd make a Polygon class (you name it) with a vector inside, then have simply a `vector<Polygon>`, which instantly explains what it means, rather than `vector<vector<int>>`, which doesn't contain any context or reveal what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ is a call-by-value language. This means, modifications to function arguments are usually only visible during the execution of the function. That's why your assignements

```
PointMaxi=i;
PointMaxj=j;
PointMaxk=k;
```

are lost once the function returned.

C++ can also use call-by-reference by means of appending `&` to the data type in the parameter list. In that case, the function signature would be

```
double Process (vector<vector<int>>& vec,
                int& PointMaxi,
                int& PointMaxj,
                int& PointMaxk)
```

and the effects of your assignments would be visible in the calling function.

Alternatively, you can define a stuct consisting of a `double` and three `int` and use that as a return type for the processing function.

Answer (score 0):

As Oswald mentioned there are two ways of passing arguments in C++, by value and by reference.  The intuition is that when an argument is passed by reference it is *copied* and the copy is passed to the function, so you cannot change the original.  The intuition of passing by reference is that the original is passed to the function *without copying* so you can change the original.  For example, run the following code and check the output.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// i is passed by value, j is passed by reference using the '&' operator.
void value_and_reference(int i, int &j) {
    i = 10;
    j = 20;
}

int main() {

    int i = 0, j = 0;
    value_and_reference(i, j);
    cout << "i : " << i << endl; // Prints 0
    cout << "j : " << j << endl; // Prints 20
    return 0;
}
```

You need to change your output parameters (`PointMaxi`, `PointMaxj`, `PointMaxk`) to be passed by reference so the originals get modified.